# Formula out of margin

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I got some issues while writing a formula in LaTeX. I have to print this in my document:

```
\textit{P3ACM}: $ \left \langle \left \langle ( 09.00, 18.00 ) , \{ Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursady, Friday \} \right \rangle , \left \langle NOW,  24/12/11:23.59 \right \rangle \right \rangle $
```

but once I compile it, the formula gets off the margins used in the whole document.
I just started using LaTeX so I'm not so good, would you please suggest me how to get over this problem?

Answer (score 6):

As @carlpett mentioned, LaTeX does not break lines in mathmode automatically. You have to tell it where to perform the breaking. And yes, extensible delimiters specified by `\left` and `\right` pairs need to be paired on the same line. A consolation is the use of `\left.` and `\right.` to be the "missing" pair on the left/right of another delimiter. However, this does not bode well if the contents between `\left` and `\right` are of different sizes between line breaks. For this, `\vphantom{<stuff>}` prints a zero-width rectangle with height exactly that of `<stuff>`. This way you can break equations the way you want to, and stretch the height of the extensible delimiters to match each other, even across lines.

A good example mixing all these ideas is contained in section **8.1.1 Braces over several lines** (page 25) in Herbert Voß' [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

Alternatively, foregoing the use of extensible delimiters, you could resize delimiters using any of the following: `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, `\Bigg`, or `\bigl`, `\bigr`, `\Bigl`, `\Bigr`, `\biggl`, `\biggr`, `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` from the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Here is an example from the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) that highlights this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[\sum_i a_i\left|\sum_j x_{ij}\right|^p\right]^{1/p}
  \quad \text{versus} \quad
  \biggl[\sum_i a_i\Bigl\lvert\sum_j x_{ij}\Bigr\rvert^p\biggr]^{1/p}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Different extensible delimiters]

Comment: IIRC, the `@` user notification works in comments, but not in answers.

Comment: @lockstep: [I know](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/599#599), but I wanted to credit some of the discussion given by @ carlpett (who won't be notified by this comment, by the way). :-|

Comment: `\[bB]ig(g)?[lr]?` doesn't come from the amsmath!

Comment: @Werner: At the risk of being pedatic, the question is about _inline_ math which TeX does break across lines automatically. There the only problem is that `\left...\right` constructs can't be broken.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX does not insert line breaks in mathmode, you'll have to do it manually. I'd suggest using the `align` environment, in which you can easily align your lines so they look nice. For instance:

```
\begin{align}
    math &math math \\
    &more math
\end{align}
```

The `\\` breaks the line, and LaTeX will then line up the `&`s.

Comment: so it should be something like this? \begin{align}
\textit{P3ACM}: & \left \langle \left \langle ( 09.00, 18.00 ) , \{ Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursady, Friday \} \right \rangle , \& \left \langle NOW,  24/12/11:23.59 \right \rangle \right \rangle
\end{align}      cause it didn't work

Comment: What is the error? I think `\textit` doesn't like being in a math environment, so that might be it. Also, this will not be inline, as your original code was. If you need that, I think you'll have to manually break your code by exiting and entering math mode where you want the line break

Comment: i took out \textit and left only \\ (no &, just to try) and the error is:  "Extra }, or forgotten \right." this is the code changed: \begin{align}
P3ACM:  \left \langle \left \langle ( 09.00, 18.00 ) , \{ Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursady, Friday \} \right \rangle ,  \\ 
 \left \langle NOW,  24/12/11:23.59 \right \rangle \right \rangle 
\end{align}

Comment: @breathe0: Ok, turns out `\left` and `\right` need to be matched per line. So add a `\right.` at the end of the first line, and a `\left.` at the beginning of the first.